# Cannot connect to local db

Tags: sql-server, installation, plugins

I am in a Supply Chain Masters program and need to install the Excel Data Mining add-in for Excel. I downloaded and installed [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP1 Data Mining Add-ins for Microsoft® Office®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35578).

This package includes two add-ins for Microsoft Office Excel (Table Analysis Tools and Data Mining Client) and one add-in for Microsoft Office Visio 2010 (Data Mining Templates). The add-ins are supported on Office 2010 and Office 2013.

Once installed, I cannot connect to *localhost*. I run two separate accounts: an admin account and a regular account. I've tried starting the service and it doesn't work.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall several times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed? Have you verified that it is running? What is the instance name? How *exactly* are you trying to connect to localhost? What does "cannot connect" and "doesnt work" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: i believe i do; installed SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 64 Bit; for some reason it has stopped running. not sure what i am doing wrong here. i am trying to connect via the data mining add-in. selecting new server name localhost selecting the dropping down from the catalog drop down and i get the error "a connection cannot be made ensure that the server is running" again not sure what i am doing wrong here. maybe more complicated that i first thought.

Comment: Where have you verified that it has stopped running? Did you verify that you installed a default instance? Express is often `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this download **SQL Server® 2012 SP1 Data Mining** is not a SQL Server database service. Its just a tool/add-on to work with Office and connect to a database.

You must install SQL Server to connect to the database.

[Microsoft offers Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) to use locally with no licence need.

Comment: i have installed "SqlLocalDB", i then tried to install  "SQL_AS_DMAddin" which was essentially the same thing. the error i get when trying to connect to local host is "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. i am very unfamiliar with SQL and didn't think trying to install this data mining add-in would be this difficult. any advice on what i could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any step by step directions would be appreciated, i honestly didnt think it would be this difficult to install SQL and the data mining add-in. i tried installing SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 64 Bit & SQL Server 2014 Express 64 Bit. essentially the same as the add-in. at a lost to be honest. appreciate the assistance.